# Converting a string to a double so I can filter by value listview

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I currently have a string property called Monthly which is a float calculation then coverted to a string. Once all my properties are saved I'm wanting to filter them with Monthly. By doing so I believe I need to convert Monthly to a double but by doing so I'm getting an exception saying "Input string was not in a correct format." Below is my code...

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
            var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>().ToList().OrderBy(APR => Convert.ToDecimal(APR.Monthly));

            APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;


        }
    }
```

Surely I can't convert it back to a string?

Comment: According to that message, there is at least one value that cannot be converted to decimal.

Comment: Monthly should be stored as a decimal in the first place

Comment: yea Its monthly as its a string. Any idea of a work around though?

Comment: @Jason long story short I was originally using RealmDB which doesn't allow decimals

Comment: look at your data and figure out which one is a bad value and fix it.  If you can't do that, add a read-only property to your model that will handle the bad data when converting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a read-only property to your model to handle the conversion

```
public decimal MonthlyDecimal 
{
  get 
  {
    try {
      return Convert.ToDecimal(Monthly);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a string mate it has a £ at the start

Comment: your entire question is "how to sort a decimal" - a "£" is not a decimal.  You use this field to perform the sort.  If your data contains a "£" then that is obviously why your conversion is failing.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one value that cannot be converted to decimal. You can try a workaround like:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
            var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>()
                .ToList()
                .OrderBy(APR => decimal.TryParse(APR.Monthly, out decimal m)?m:0);

            APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: You can add parameters to that TryParse, to parse for a specific culture and also include symbols for currency etc.

EDIT: I see that you have £ in your values, probably denoting currencies in UK:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
            var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>()
                .ToList()
                .OrderBy(APR => decimal.TryParse(APR.Monthly, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), out decimal m)?m:0);

            APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store and use the value as a double in the first place. When you need it as a string, for displaying, then convert it to a string easily by calling ToString on the double, and a that time you can add the £ to the front of the string, e.g.:

```
"£" + doubleValue.ToString()
```

or

```
$"£{doubleValue.ToString()}"
```

Alternately, if you need or really want to store the value as a string with the £ starting it off, then you need to first strip off the £ before converting to double, e.g.:

```
double doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(stringValue.Replace("£", ""));
```